# lots of redirect chains WordPress site on ngix + php fpm

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx, php

until I added the string: remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); to functions.php of current theme the site even did not load in browser. Now it loads ok, but when I checked site load with tools.pingdom I saw dozens of those "Remove the following redirect chain if possible" errors. Each of them is the same error about some image:

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/thumbs/fgd/0-9/10-bullets.png
http://domain.com/wp-content/thumbs/fgd/0-9/10-bullets.png

etc. about 200 of the same kind.

It is a game arcade plugin and those are paths to thumbnails of games. Could you point me where to dig?

Comment: Is your site meant to have a mandatory www? The site authoritative domain is configured at wordpress's dashboard, but nginx could be 301 redirecting too.

Comment: no, www not necessary. How to check this out?

Comment: wordpress dashboard -> settings -> general, see what's on the ```WordPress Address (URL)``` item

Comment: this field without www

Comment: I've tried both fields (siteurl and home) with www and both without, no effect.

Comment: ok, what about your nginx vhost. Can you post whatever rules do you have in there?

Comment: didn't saw your question. here is my config for the site:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TB8VtMpG

Comment: and here is the .htaccess# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress'

Comment: Ok. htaccess has nothing to do and nginx ignores it anyway. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that you have (or used to have) your wordpress site configured at the url www.domain.com

This means that any images you pasted on your posts began with www.domain.com.

It's possible that images on your theme are also hard linked to www.domain.com too.

Your nginx vhost has these rules

```
server_name         www.domain.com domain.com;

if ($host != 'domain.com') {
    rewrite ^/(.*)     http://domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Which mean "listen to either www.domain.com or domain.com, but force whoever request the www domain to perform another request in order to end up at domain.com."

This is meant to canonicalize your site url and avoid google indexing your content twice, which would split pagerank and authority and probably downrate it as duplicate content.

The problem is that this rule operates on the images you already have linked ar www.domain.com, so everytime you request them, nginx redirects you.

**TL/DR**

Make sure the url you have configured at your wordpress installation matches the one you're enforcing in your nginx vhost. If you want to strip the www part, fine, but do it in both parts.

Second: for the images on your theme, you'll have to manually edit the urls to get rid of the www. You can also use relative links

```
<img src="/wp-content/thumbs/fgd/0-9/10-bullets.png">
```

instead of

```
<img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/thumbs/fgd/0-9/10-bullets.png">
```

Third: do the same check for the posts you have published until now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Amenadiel. That advice helped to solve my problem: I've replaced all img links starting with "www.domain.com" in mysql db with "domain.com" and no more redirects )))

Comment: by the way how do you think, the config that I'm using is correct? or better to change the "if" part with for example this one:    server {

listen 80;

server_name www.domain.com;

return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;

}

Comment: Yes, I use that syntax for my redirects. Using ifs in nginx is a waste of resources.

Comment: Very appreciate your help! Could I add you in skype?